# Linq where with strange condition

Tags: linq, generics, merge, where-clause, observablecollection

I'm struggling to understand this lines of code but I don't grow out of it.

The instruction is the following

`var targetHandles = target.Where(t => true);`

that is inside a function with these signature

```
public static void Merge<T>(ObservableCollection<T> target, ObservableCollection<T> source) where T : DtoBase
```

Thanks in advance for your answers

Ric

Comment: [Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0). This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its `GetEnumerator` method directly or by using `foreach`. The condition really doesn't make any sense unless the only objective was to get the `WhereEnumerableIterator`

Comment: One possiblity is that `targetHandles` will be modified later with additional calls to LINQ methods, so you want its type to be `IEnumerable<T>` instead of e.g. `List<T>` or `T[]` so you can re-assign it (e.g. `targetHandles = targetHandles.Where(x => pred(x));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your problem is only in the `Where` of LINQ, or in the `where T: DtoBase`, so I'll discuss both

### Where in a generic method

```
public static void Merge<T>(ObservableCollection<T> target,
                            ObservableCollection<T> source)
                            where T : DtoBase
```

The `<T>` after the identifier of the method `Merget<T>`, tells us that this is a `generic method`, which means that you can call it with all kinds of classes, as long as the class meets the `where` condition:

```
where T : DtoBase
```

So you can call this method with any class T, as long as this class is (derived from) `DtoBase`.

Examples:

```
class DtoBase {...};
class Derived : DtoBase {...};

ObservableCollection<DtoBase> myBases = ...
ObservableCollection<DtoBase> yourBases = ...

ObservableCollection<Derived> myDeriveds = ...
ObservableCollection<Derived> yourDeriveds = ...
```

Now you can call method `Merge`, and replace every Occurence ot `T` with anything that matches `where T : DtoBase`. So the following are all valid:

```
Merge(myBases, yourBases);
Merge(myBases, myBases);
Merge(myDeriveds, yourDeriveds);
Merge(myBases, myDeriveds);
```

The following won't compile:

```
Merge(myBases, 4);         // integer 4 is not a DtoBase
Merge("Hello", myBases);   // string is not a DtoBase
```

### Where in a LINQ statement

```
var targetHandles = target.Where(t => true);
```

The `t` in this statement has nothing to do with the T in the generic method.

If you look at the definition of [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) you'll see that it is a generic extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource,bool> predicate);
```

Generic is discussed above: Where has a type `TSource`, comparable with the `T` we discussed earlier: wherever you see `TSource` you should replace it with the same actual type.

We also see the keyword `this` in front of the first parameter. This means that it is an extension method: you can put the first parameter in front of the method, like this:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = ...
IEnumerable<Product> cheapProducts = products.Where(product => product.Price < 1);
```

This is the same as:

```
IEnumerable<Product> cheapProducts = Enumerable<Product>.Where(products,
    product => product.Price < 1);
```

So extension method is just some fancy syntactic sugar.  It makes it look as if it is a method of Product.

Now the fun part: the `product` in `product => product.Price < 1`. product is just an identifier with a well chosen name. I could also have written:

```
.Where(t => t.Price < 1);
```

the `t => t.Price < 1` is called a lambda expression. It is some shorthand for a function definition: we create a method with input parameter `t`, which returns `t.price < 1`. The type of `t` can be found in the generic:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource,bool> predicate);
```

In my example `TSource` was a `Product`, so the first parameter should be `IEnumerable<Product>`. The return value is also `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = ...
IEnumerable<Product> cheapProducts = products.Where(...);
```

`predicate` is a `Func<TSource, bool>`. This means: any function, with input TSource (which is in our case a Product), that returns a bool. So if you see somewhere:

```
Func<int, string, DateTime, Point>
```

Then it means: any method with three input parameters of type int, string, DateTime (in this order), which returns a Point:

```
Point MyFunct(int i, string txt, DateTime date) {...}
```

We've seen that the lambda expression `t => t.Price < 1` is a method that takes a `Product t` as input parameter and returns the value of `t.Price < 1`, which obviously is a Boolean. Hence, this lambda expression matches Func<TSource,bool>.

```
IEnumerable<Product> cheapProducts = products.Where(product => product.Price < 1);
```

So what does this do? It takes every `product` from the sequence of `products`, and puts this in the function `product => product.Price < 1`. In other words: from every product in the sequence of Products, it calculates the Boolean `product.Price < 1`. It it is true, then we keep it, if not, we don't use it in the sequence returned by the `Where`.

The effect is, that `Where(product => product.Price < 1)` returns the sequence of all Products with a value for property Price that is less than 1.

### Back to your question

Your `Where` is a rather strange one.

```
IEnumerable<Target> targets = ...
targets.Where(t => true);
```

We know that `targets` is a sequence of type Target. Hence, we know that the predicate is a method that takes as input one Target, and returns a bool:

bool Predicate(Target t) { return true}

Well, it does return a boolean. In fact, it always returns the same boolean, it doesn't even look at the input parameter t, it always returns true.

`Where(t => true)` is similar to the following:

```
foreach(Target target in targets)
{
    if (true) return target;
}
```

Well, this doesn't do a lot: it returns the complete input sequence:

```
IEnumerable<Target> targets = ...
var result = targets.Where(t => true);
```

We know that `result` has the same elements, in the same order as `targets`. The statement is not very useful.

### Final remark

Whenever you have to define your own identifiers in LINQ statements, try to use plural nouns to identify sequences, use singular nouns to identify elements of the sequences. Try to avoid meaningless identifiers as `t =>`.

> typing less characters is not a good excuse for choosing bad identifiers!

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = ...
IEnumerable<Order> orders = ...

var customersWithTheirOrders = customer.GroupJoin(orders,

    customer => customer.Id,       // from every Customer take the primary key
    order => order.CustomerId,     // from every Order take the foreign key

    (customer, ordersOfThisCustomer) => new
    {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
        Address = customer.Address,

        Orders = ordersOfThisCustomer.Select(order => new
        {
            Date = order.Date,
            Total = order.Total,
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
```

This is a very big LINQ. You might not be familiar with `GroupJoin`, but because I used plural and singular nouns, it is not very difficult to read:

In words: We have a sequence of Customers and a sequence of Orders. We GroupJoin the Customers and the Orders. This means, that from every Customer we take the Id, from every Order we take the CustomerId. We try to match them. From every customer with his zero or more Orders, we make one new object.

This new object contains the Id of the Customer, as well as his Name and his Address. From every Order in the sequence of Orders of this Customer, we make one new object. This new object contains the Date and the Total of the Order.

Because I used plural and singular nouns, this textual description corresponds very much with the LINQ. You don't have to wonder what `t` and `x` are. `Customer` and `OrdersOfThisCustomer` are much easier to understand what they stand for.